# How can I use exposed filter likes "views tree" in views of content?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I want to add exposed filter that shows taxonomy parents and children to views, this view's type is content.
Clearly my goal isn't creating menu by taxonomy, my goal is creating exposed filter for content of views.

Like Below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Taxonomy Menu module looks like just what you're after.

https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu

Comment: May you explain about it? How can I use it for exposed filter?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better solution for this is [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). Just add the exposed filter as you normally do and use Better Exposed Filter with checkboxes. That's it.